# Can't get woff or svg files from presumed source

Tags: css, browser, svg, fonts

I'm trying to get a few font files.

Repro steps:

- Open https://www.idahohumanesociety.org/assets/css/fonts.css
- See `url('../fonts/museo_slab_100-MuseoSlab.woff') format('woff')` in stylesheet
- Try opening https://www.idahohumanesociety.org/assets/fonts/museo_slab_100-MuseoSlab.woff
- See **"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."**
- Happens just the same for `url('../fonts/museo_slab_100-MuseoSlab.svgz#webfont8mNmLs65') format('svg')`
- However, works for the `eot` and `ttf` files

Happening for me in FF and Chrome. Anyone understand why this is happening?

Comment: Off-topic because it involves the non-availabity of a resource on a non SE site.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it really isn't there – [everything but IE can use ttf](http://caniuse.com/#search=ttf) and [IE can use eot](http://caniuse.com/#search=eot).